# Given $E = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: a < x < b\}$, prove that $[a,b] \subset \partial E$

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently studying for my real analysis midterms and as such, I am doing the older midterms. I have currently reached the question asked in the title, that is:

Given $E = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: a < x < b\}$, prove that $[a,b] \subset \partial E$

Now, I have written down a proof, but I am not completely sure that it is valid and so I wanted to get an opinion here. The proof goes as follow:

First, we show that the interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is empty. To do that, see that $\mathring{\mathbb{Q}} = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: \exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}, \delta > 0, (x-\delta, x+\delta) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}\}$. However, there exists no such $\delta$ since $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\mathring{\mathbb{Q}} = \emptyset$.

Secondly, it is given that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$, and so $\partial \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \emptyset = \mathbb{R}$.

Finally, since $E \subset \mathbb{Q}$, we find by definition that $[a,b] \subset \partial E$.

And so, my question is: can I confidently say this or are the first and second steps not strong enough to ensure the last result?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the $\partial$ symbol as you use it here.  Does it refer to the set's boundary (the difference between its closure and its interior)?

Comment: Yes, I was not sure if this was common notation, but it is the one we use in my class.

Comment: The first and second step are okay. But in the last part, what do you do exactly?

Comment: Well, since $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $\partial E \subset \partial \mathbb{Q} \implies \partial E \subset \mathbb{R}$ and since $E$ is bounded by $a$ and $b$, $[a,b] \subset \partial E$. However, I'm not sure if this argument holds.

Comment: I'm not sure of that argument because $\partial C =C$ and is bounded by $0$ and $1$, with $C$ the usual Cantor. But its enough with the first and second steps, because you can approximate an irrational in $[a,b]$ with rationals and intersect this sequence witht $E$, so $[a,b] = ([a,b]\cap Q) \cup ([a,b]\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})) \subset \partial E$

Comment: What do you mean by "the usual Cantor"? Also, it would suffice to change the last line to your suggestion to complete the proof?

Comment: That usual Cantor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set
And yes, it is suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty good.  I don't really like your final step though. I feel it could be clearer.

Alternatively,  why not just set out to prove it directly?

Given $x\in [a,b]$, we need $x\in\partial E$.  By definition,  $x\in \partial E$ if $\forall\epsilon\gt0$ we have $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap E\setminus \{x\}\neq\emptyset$.

This is true, since, firstly, (as you say) $\bar{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$.  That is,  $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.
In particular,  $E=\Bbb Q\cap (a,b)$ is dense in $[a,b]$.  That takes care of the irrationals in the interval.

Put this together with the fact that  there is a sequence of rationals converging to any rational. That is,  we need to know any rational in $[a,b]$ is a *limit point* of $E$.

For, $x\in \partial E$ iff $x$ is a limit point of $E$ (this is true in general).

Comment: This makes sense as a whole, we deconstruct this in two parts, the irrationals and the rationals of the interval. I can understand the proof for the irrationals, we can always find an $\epsilon$ such that there is an element of $E$ inside the open interval without $x$. However, I'm not sure I follow your reasoning for the rationals of the interval?

Comment: Given $\frac pq$, you can construct a sequence of rationals converging to it.  Say $\frac{p+\frac1n}q$, for instance.

Comment: But how does it tell us that such a rational is a limit point of $E$ and thus $[a,b] \subset \partial E$? I feel like I'm not really grasping how to combine these statements to get the solution.

Comment: The sequence of rationals will eventually be in the interval,  $[a,b]$.  Thus we get a sequence in $E$ converging to the (rational)  point.

Comment: Or you could use the fact that the irrationals are dense;  together with the fact that any two irrationals have a rational between them.  Either way, there is a sequence in $E$ converging to any $x\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea, but if your reasoning isn't convincing yourself, then you need to add a little bit more. I would try appealing straight to the definitions. Recall that $\partial E = \overline{E} \setminus E^\circ$, so you need to show that $[a, b] \subset \overline{E}$ and $[a, b] \cap E^\circ = \emptyset$.

As per your first step, the interior of $\Bbb{Q}$ is empty. If $c \in E^\circ$, then there would exist some $r > 0$ such that $B(c; r) \subset E \subset \Bbb{Q}$, which would put $c \in \Bbb{Q}^\circ = \emptyset$. Thus, $[a, b] \cap E^\circ = [a, b] \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Your second step really does need some fleshing out. You will, of course, use the density of rationals, but density doesn't survive the process of taking subsets necessarily. Just knowing $\overline{\Bbb{Q}} = \Bbb{R}$ doesn't tell us too much about the closure of a subset of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Suppose $x \in (a, b)$. Then, consider the open sets $(x - \delta / n, x + \delta / n)$, where $\delta = \min \{ x - a, b - x\}$. Then these open sets are contained in $(a, b)$. By the density of $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$, there exists some
$$x_n \in \Bbb{Q} \cap (x - \delta / n, x + \delta / n) \subset \Bbb{Q} \cap (a, b) = E.$$
But then $|x_n - x| < \delta / n$, hence $x_n \to x$. That is, $x \in \overline{E}$.

It only remains to show $a, b \in \overline{E}$. We can show $a \in \overline{E}$ by considering open sets of the form $\left(a, a + \frac{b - a}{n}\right)$, and similarly $b \in \overline{E}$ using sets of the form $\left(b - \frac{b - a}{n}, b\right)$. After you establish this, you're done.